# Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine: try to authenticate

Tags: authentication, doctrine, zend-framework2

I´m trying to authenticate in Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine:

I think i added everything which I need to Module.php + module.config.php

In my Controller I do:

```
$authService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');
$adapter = $authService->getAdapter();
$adapter->setIdentityValue($formdata['username']);
$adapter->setCredentialValue($formdata['password']);
$authResult = $adapter->authenticate();
```

It works until $adapter->authenticate();

Error is:

> Warning: class_parents(): Class does not exist and could not be loaded
>   in
>   /.../doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php
>   on line 40

```
public function getParentClasses($class)
{
      return class_parents($class); //Line 40
}
```

Comment: Did you validate your mappings first? Also may be a metadata caching issue: clear your caches.